# Is it possible to create a custom sorting key at the column level in a MediaWiki table?

Tags: sorting, mediawiki

Using https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Sorting and other similar guides, I see that it's possible to assign a custom sorting key to specific rows using data-sort-value. Is it possible to create a key at the column level that will sort all data in that column by that key?

The end goal is to be able to take a column of data that uses alphanumeric characters and sort them in a way makes sense in context as opposed to the default alphabetic or numeric options available with data-sort-type. Since many tables on the site will be using the same sorting key for this particular column, it makes more sense to apply it at the column level than to each row of every table.

Alternatively if MediaWiki doesn't have the above sorting feature, is it possible to create a custom data-sort-type in MediaWiki? If so, where would I start?

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by column key. Do you want to reorder columns? If you want to order rows, how would a column-level key help? In any case, you can write your own [parser](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/c42f06642091e1cb1142066b0a52a69a0c7e783d/resources/src/jquery/jquery.tablesorter.js#L1060).